# change db column default from NULL to <null>

Tags: insert, default-value

When inserting rows in table, a default value is a NULL. Is their a way to make

```
"<null>"
```

such that,

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| prev_id      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| package      | text        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| app          | text        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

looks like this.

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | <null>            | auto_increment |
| prev_id      | int(11)     | YES  |     | <null>            |                |
| package      | text        | YES  |     | <null>            |                |
| app          | text        | YES  |     | <null>            |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: What?! Why? What are you trying to achieve? This is mysql I assume? (please tag as such). How are you inserting?

Comment: estimate of an answer, leave formatting of `NULL` values to the application layer. If really needed at SQL layer, `SELECT COALESE(prev_id, '<null>') as prev_id ..` on retrieval.

Comment: Yon can declare the column like: package text default '<null>' For prev_id thats not possible of course